# JSP substring() doesn't display anything if String is shorter

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I want to display the beginning of a text in a table in my Struts2 application. It works just fine, except if the text field is shorter than the length I want.

```
<td>
    <s:property value="key.text.substring(0,40)" />...
</td>
```

If `key.text` is too short, nothing is displayed. Everything is well displayed if I remove the `substring()` function (but it's often too long, of course).

Is there anything that I can do except testing `text` length ?

Comment: Possible only with `key.text.length>40`

Comment: For example `Would you like to know how am I or not ?` is displayed, `How old am I ?` is not.

Comment: I meant what kind of solution do you expect? Besides checking length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you are running into an exception here:

> substring
>
> ...
>
> **Throws: IndexOutOfBoundsException** - if the beginIndex is negative, or endIndex is larger than the length of this String object, or beginIndex is larger than endIndex.

This is the reason why you don't see any output.

Hence you need to check for the length first.

Comment: Well, I didn't see any exception and I find this test a bit useless, but let's do it then.

Comment: set `struts.devMode` to true, and you'll see the exception

Answer (score 3):

Pass to the bright side of the Force and use CSS only for this...

<kbd>[Running Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZLx5B/)</kbd>

HTML

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><s:property value="key.text"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
td {
    overflow:hidden;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap; 
    display: inline-block;
    width:200px;
}
```

This way you will have a precise control on the overall width, since you express it in pixels, while limiting a number of chars, your width can't be predicted: (40 `I` are shorter than 40 `Z`).

Comment: Never heard of this. It seems nice !

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<td>
   <s:if test="key.text.length() > 40"> 
      <s:property value="key.text.substring(0,40)" />
   </s:if>
   <s:else>
      <s:property value="key.text" />
   </s:else>
</td>
```

Comment: short if-condition, don't know the syntax with struts2

Comment: Like this? `<s:if test="key.text.length() > 40" ? <s:property value="key.text.substring(0,40)" /> : <s:property value="key.text" /> >`